# Unable to find assembly exception,when perform deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core

My winforms application has a custom control, one of its property "LayoutStream" is `byte[]` type and it is serializable property. Currently I have ported my application from 4.6 framework to NetCore 3.0 project.

While run ported NetCore 3.0 project, im getting below exception when deserialize the data from resx file.

```
this.control1.LayoutStream = ((SerializableByteList)(resources.GetObject("control1.LayoutStream")));


    public SerializableByteList LayoutStream
    {
        get
        {
            return LayoutStream;
        }
        set
        {
            LayoutStream= value;
            if (value != null)
                this.stmLayout.Write(value.Bytes.ToArray(), 0, value.Bytes.ToArray().Length);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class SerializableByteList 
    {
        public SerializableByteList()
        {
            Bytes = new List<byte>();
        }
        public List<byte> Bytes { get; set; }
    }
```

> Exception Occurs:
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
>   Unable to find assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Please suggest solution to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, `BinaryFormatter` *is not portable*; it was *designed* for remoting between two nodes running identical code, not persisting data between frameworks. So: my *main* advice is simply:

> Don't use `BinaryFormatter`. Ever.

I realise this boat may have sailed, but a very pragmatic option is to:

- pick a new serializer - making sure it is portable (json, xml, protobuf, etc); just about *anything except `BinaryFormatter`*
- in your old code, deserialize the data with your current code, and serialize it separately with the new choice of serializer
- in your new code, deserialize it in the new format only

---

At a *push*, however, you could try playing with a custom `SerializationBinder`; the idea here is that you subclass `SerializationBinder`, override the methods, and tell it where to find things. The fundamental problem here is that:

1. the assemblies (mscorlib etc) have changed identity
2. types have moved *between* assemblies in many cases

Both of those problems need handling.

Partial code:

```cs
var bf = new BinaryFormatter { Binder = MyBinder.Instance };
// etc
```

with

```
class MyBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    private MyBinder() { }
    public static MyBinder Instance { get; } = new MyBinder();
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        // TODO: check assemblyName and typeName against some known list, and
        // return the Type that should be used, often *instead of* the
        // one it expected;
    }
    public override void BindToName(Type serializedType,
        out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        //TODO: the opposite
    }
}
```

---

But this is hard work, and *absurdly* brittle. Your time would be *much* better spent porting to a different serializer, IMO. Happy to recommend some, depending on your needs.

---

Side note: they have tried *repeatedly* to kill `BinaryFormatter` for .NET Core, but it sadly survived.

Comment: Any other possible solution to use binary formatter?

Comment: @MageshMaggi I'm unclear how to parse that question; if you mean "any way of making it work without changing from `BinaryFormatter`?" - yes, you write your own `SerializationBinder`. If you mean "any way of making it work *without using* `BinaryFormatter`?" - yes: pick another serializer; I'd lean towards protobuf-net, but I'm biased

Comment: Could you please explain, how SerializationBinder will help to resolve this case?

Comment: @MageshMaggi k; `BinaryFormatter` stores type metadata as strings; it is the job of the binder to convert those persisted strings into `Type`, or a `Type` into the strings you want to store. The *default* behavior uses "just look for an assembly called `assemblyName`, and inside that: look for a type called `typeName`". Which is fine until *someone changes the assembly identity, or moves the type*. Your custom binder can recognize problematic strings (probably by debugging it and seeing what it asks for) and *you can give it back the appropriate types*.

Comment: @MageshMaggi the good news is that IIRC: you can return `null` if you don't want to impact how a *specific* type behaves - so you only need to handle the ones that *are problems*

Comment: Could you please provide any example which explains about this?

Comment: @MageshMaggi `if(assemblyName == "something.that.is.failing" && typeName == "Not.Working") return typeof(HereItIs); /* x 6 */ return null;`

Comment: Your solution may be work by handled manually. But in my case, I cannot handle it manaully, since it is updated through winforms designers and corresponding values generated in resx file.

I need to de serialize the from resx file.

Comment: @MageshMaggi well, one could argue you just haven't added enough special cases yet :) As I said: it isn't going to be fun or easy, which is why it generally *isn't a good idea to use `BinaryFormatter`*. Maybe rethinking the way you're bundling these things might be useful? I appreciate this must be frustrating, but the reality is : I don't have a magic wand here, and I can't make `BinaryFormatter` be something that it isn't.