# C# BinaryFormatter.Deserialize failed with exception

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I tried the sample code in 
[BinaryFormatter.Deserialize Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.deserialize?view=netframework-4.8), when I debug in Visual Studio, the result is as expected. While when I execute the exe file directly in the debug folder, it will get **"End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed"** exception.

This only happens, when I set the project target framework to ".NET Framework 4.8" or 4.7 version. like below:
[image] 
Error message: 
[image]

It's even more strange that this only happens when using.net 4.7 and 4.8 version. If I change to .net 4.0 version, this problem will disappeared, and even switch back to .net 4.7 and 4.8. It will no longer happens any more.

Looks like there are some dependencies missing in higher .net version for "BinaryFormatter.Deserialize" ? Bugs for the .net framework? Anyone knows how to solve this problem ?

Also record a video for this problem :
https://www.screencast.com/t/nC38Sm3q3pVQ

The code is like below :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public class App 
{
[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
    Serialize();
    Deserialize();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void Serialize() 
{
    // Create a hashtable of values that will eventually be serialized.
    Hashtable addresses = new Hashtable();
    addresses.Add("Jeff", "123 Main Street, Redmond, WA 98052");
    addresses.Add("Fred", "987 Pine Road, Phila., PA 19116");
    addresses.Add("Mary", "PO Box 112233, Palo Alto, CA 94301");

    // To serialize the hashtable and its key/value pairs,  
    // you must first open a stream for writing. 
    // In this case, use a file stream.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

    // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialize the data to the stream.
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    try 
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fs, addresses);
    }
    catch (SerializationException e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally 
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
}


static void Deserialize() 
{
    // Declare the hashtable reference.
    Hashtable addresses  = null;

    // Open the file containing the data that you want to deserialize.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open);
    try 
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Deserialize the hashtable from the file and 
        // assign the reference to the local variable.
        addresses = (Hashtable) formatter.Deserialize(fs);
    }
    catch (SerializationException e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally 
    {
        fs.Close();
    }

    // To prove that the table deserialized correctly, 
    // display the key/value pairs.
    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in addresses) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} lives at {1}.", de.Key, de.Value);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What are you trying to deserialize? Is this object serialized using .Net 4?

Comment: a minimal repro would help, here, but **fundamentally**, my advice is simple: **do not use `BinaryFormatter`**. Ever. Sadly, I see this [multiple times a day, virtually every day](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58392086/23354), but : it really really isn't a good idea to use in the way that most people try to use it. Almost any other serializer is a much better idea and will save you vast amounts of time and stress.

Comment: Thanks for you guys to help looking into the problem. The code is just the sample code in 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.deserialize?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I just ran the sample code you referenced and had no issues either in debug or stand alone.  Are you sure you didn't miss code?  I am running VS2019 4.8... etc..

Comment: I've just record a video for this problem https://www.screencast.com/t/nC38Sm3q3pVQ

, and also attached the code in the question. 

Thanks,

Comment: @Kixoka Yes, this is very weird, only the stand alone version throw the exception. And .net 4.0 do not have such problem.  I am using VS Community 2017.

Comment: Are you running this as a console application?

Comment: yes, Console App(.net framework)

Comment: Anybody has an idea on this? This is very anonnying, if I can't fix this, I will have to use Json instead to by pass this problem . As @MarcGravell said ......

Comment: I've tried the code shown above on multiple frameworks: I can't get it to fail, sadly, which makes it hard to work on the code. But fundamentally, yes I think changing serializer would be an excellent idea, for many many reasons *with this being the least of them*. I'm biased, but protobuf-net is pretty good in many scenarios :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I ran as a console application.  The only difference is that I added a console.readkey so i can view the output.  This was 4.8 in vs2019, AnyCpu for configuration.  As I said it ran in debug mode and from the folder stand alone.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
 class Program
 {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Serialize();
        Deserialize();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Serialize()
    {
        // Create a hashtable of values that will eventually be serialized.
        Hashtable addresses = new Hashtable();
        addresses.Add("Jeff", "123 Main Street, Redmond, WA 98052");
        addresses.Add("Fred", "987 Pine Road, Phila., PA 19116");
        addresses.Add("Mary", "PO Box 112233, Palo Alto, CA 94301");

        // To serialize the hashtable and its key/value pairs,  
        // you must first open a stream for writing. 
        // In this case, use a file stream.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

        // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialize the data to the stream.
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        try
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fs, addresses);
        }
        catch (SerializationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
    }


    static void Deserialize()
    {
        // Declare the hashtable reference.
        Hashtable addresses = null;

        // Open the file containing the data that you want to deserialize.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open);
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            // Deserialize the hashtable from the file and 
            // assign the reference to the local variable.
            addresses = (Hashtable)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
        }
        catch (SerializationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            fs.Close();
        }

        // To prove that the table deserialized correctly, 
        // display the key/value pairs.
        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in addresses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} lives at {1}.", de.Key, de.Value);
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I do the same, and I used the console application, Console App(.net framework)

Seems we got different results 。。。。。。

Comment: I suspect my environment has something to do with the issue, but what's the problem might be ? 
Since if once I build  the project with .net framework 4.0, then this problem will no longer happens,  even I switch to other .net framewok that would cause trouble before. 
Something to do with GAC ?

Comment: Could be... you could always try doing a repair and see if that fixes your problem or uninstall then reinstall....  Good luck!